# URL-Rewriting help

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am new to URL rewriting and saw in many sites the effect of URL Rewriting. I am completely new to this area. Even, i am finding hard to learn this.

The help is, I want to rewrite `http://www.example.com/resources/pages/demos/any-page.html`

to

`http://www.example.com/demos/any-page.html` omitting the `resources/pages/` directory.
I hope this rewriting is possible and if please help me in providing the .htaccess code for this rewrite. I am using a linux server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_rewrite isn't the easiest thing to grasp at first. I think you'll find the following code sufficient:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^demos/(.*)\.(htm|html)$ resources/pages/$1.$2 [L]
```

This needs to be placed in the document root of your site. It will handle both .html and .htm pages and match only those pages. To match any page after the demos/ url (With any extension) use the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^demos/(.*)$ resources/pages/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Marco, i tried your method, but its not working. I went to `http://www.example.com/demos/index.html` but i get a 404 error page. I added the .htaccess file to `example.com/.htaccess`. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Does the demos folder actually exist?

Comment: Also that code worked for me - however you will need to ensure two things:

mod_rewrite is enabled and that 
`AllowOverride` is set to All in httpd.conf (Or in the "Sites-enabled" section on Ubuntu

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled and AllowOverride is set to all. when i tried, `http://www.example.com/demos/demos/index.html` it worked. A extra `demos` folder is the mistake.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Does the demos folder (the first one) exist?

Answer (score 0):

put `.htaccess` at `/`, and in that file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^demos/(.*)\.html resources/pages/demos/$1.html
```